# WP8 Back Button between applications

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have an application on Windows Phone 8 that opens a link on Internet Explorer.
The page loads until the end and when I want to go back to the application, Internet Explorer blocks and does not return.

This is my code to open the link in Internet Explorer.

```
text.NavigateUri = new Uri(url, Urikind.Absolute);
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: I detected that the problem is related with the Uri.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll  want to do something like this:

```
//After your page has finished loading
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(url, Urikind.Absolute));
```

This isn't entirely clear from your question though. Do you want to go back to the application after the user has  clicked on something in the web page or simply after the page is done loading? Either way you'll want to handle that event then call the line above.

Comment: I want to go back after the page is done loading. I'm going to try your solution and see if it is the best approach.

Comment: Did this work for you? You might want to put this in some form of a callback that waits for the page to load before executing. This seems like an odd problem to solve though, are you sure there isn't a better way than going to an external application/website?